# Identifying (and solving) polygon problem inside geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry

I've downloaded a [countries shapefile](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip) from Natural Earth. In QGIS 2.14.11-Essen, in Vector|Geometry Tools|Check Geometry Validity... I got 2 errors (actually 1).

[image: QGIS Error description]

It says the error is in the "Feature 7". Opening the Attribute Table for this layer, I see numbers for each line, beginning from 0. The 7th line contains United Arab Emirates (UAE). So I suppose the problem lies in this country.

[image: QGIS Attribute table]

Giving a zoom to selection, I see this country in yellow, and notice it has eight small islands along its northern border. Also, it has a white patch on the extreme east of its territory (which belongs to Oman), and inside this patch, another patch, which again belongs to UAE (inside the red circle below).

[image: UAE]

First question: how do I know the number of the islands, to know which ones are the polygon 8 and polygon 9 given in the error message?

In this easy case, I just supposed the problem lied in that exclave, and after removing it (and the hole where it was contained), the problem was solved.

Second question: how do I solve the geometry problem, without removing that part of UAE's territory, and preferentially by hand, node by node (so I know exactly what's going on, what is not always the case when we use "automatic correction" tools)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the results of the "Check geometry validity" tool, a polygon inside a ring inside another polygon is not valid geometry.

So to fix this geometry issue you will have to accept a less than perfect solution. One solution is to make the small polygon a separate feature.

- Click "Add polygon feature" and re-create the small polygon.  Enable snapping to vertices to make sure the re-created polygon is an exact copy.
- Delete the original small polygon, using the Delete Part tool in the Advanced Digitizing toolbar.
- Copy the attributes from the UAE feature to the new feature using the Merge Attributes tool (Advanced Digitizing toolbar). Depending on how you plan to use this shapefile, you may wish to change its name to indicate that it's only a small part of the UAE.

[image]

Now the tiny polygon is a separate feature. Running the "Check geometry validity" tool on both UAE features finds no errors.

---

How to tell what number a part of a multipart feature is:
Using identify tool, click on one part. Open the (Derived) section of the Identify Results - there is a line called "part number."

[image]

Comment: Strange that these "geometry validity" tests are no uniform at all. To QGIS this small exclave is "invalid", but for R `mask` (raster package), it's not a problem (discovered this right now). So I can't use your workaround, because it would give me a wrong mask anyway. It's probably a matter of questioning the reasoning behind the QGIS "geometry validity" (I see no reason for this, since islands inside lakes are rather common in Nature). Thank you, anyway. And btw, any idea about my first question? Anyone may need it later.

Comment: Yeah, "geometry validity" is inconsistent. QGIS even has several different tools for testing validity. The Topology Checker plugin said there was nothing wrong with this shapefile.

Comment: I edited my answer to include instructions for identifying part numbers.

Comment: Great! I just wish it wouldn't close the (Derived) section every time I click...

Comment: Use the button "Expand new results by default" on the identify panel.